# Panel is not showing up, even with setVisible(true)?

Tags: java

Here is the code, I put setVisible(true) at the end of me createGUI() method to insure both panels would be accounted for. The bottom panel does not seem to appear there should be a JTextField a "clear" button and a label. It should look like a basic version of the calculator, like the image attached. Did I put setVisible(true) in the wrong place or is there another error(s)? Thanks in advance.

[Correct Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBEbP.png)

```
    import java.awt.event.;
    import java.awt.;
    import javax.swing.*;
```

```
class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    static Panel panel,panel2;
    static Button n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8,n9,n0,subtract,
                   add,divide,multi,clear,equals,decimal;
    static JTextField userInput;
    static JLabel label;

    //static boolean numberFlag = false;
    //static boolean operatorFlag = false;

    public void createGUI(){
        panel = new Panel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        userInput = new JTextField(15);
        panel.add(userInput);
        label = new JLabel("");
        clear = new Button("Clear");
        clear.setSize(new Dimension(4,4));
        panel.add(userInput,FlowLayout.LEFT);
        panel.add(clear,  FlowLayout.CENTER );
        panel.add(label, FlowLayout.RIGHT);

        panel2 = new Panel();
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
        n1 = new Button("1");
        n2 = new Button("2");
        n3 = new Button("3");
        n4 = new Button("4");
        n5 = new Button("5");
        n6 = new Button("6");
        n7 = new Button("7");
        n8 = new Button("8");
        n9 = new Button("9");
        n0 = new Button("0");
        add = new Button("+");
        subtract = new Button("-");
        multi = new Button("*");
        divide = new Button("/");
        equals = new Button("=");

        panel2.add(n7);
        panel2.add(n8);
        panel2.add(n9);
        panel2.add(add);
        panel2.add(n4);
        panel2.add(n5);
        panel2.add(n6);
        panel2.add(subtract);
        panel2.add(n1);
        panel2.add(n2);
        panel2.add(n3);
        panel2.add(multi);
        panel2.add(n0);

        panel2.add(equals);
        panel2.add(divide);

        add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(panel2);

        setSize(500,300);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`panel` shows up if you replace `BorderLayout.CENTER` with one of these:
`BorderLayout.NORTH`
`BorderLayout.SOUTH`
`BorderLayout.WEST`
`BorderLayout.EAST`